# Adding onClickListener inside ViewPager Makes the Swipe not Smooth Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

The swipe of ViewPager is smooth inside the vertical scrollview when I add this code into my ViewPager.

```
mPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

But when I add onClickListener to my ImageView [which is found in the Fragment added to the Adapter of the Viewpager], the swipe of my ViewPager is incorrect. Incorrect wherein I need to have a STRAIGHT HORIZONTAL LINE swipe for it to go to another page unlike before [when I did not add the onClickListener], the viewpager goes to the next page even I do DIAGONAL swiping. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used setontouchlistener to my imageview and set conditions there.

Here's the code:

```
imgCarousel.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        pStart = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {               
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:{
        Point pCancel = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

        int difference = pStart.x - pCancel.x;
        if(difference > 10){
            mPager.setCurrentItem(HomeCarousel.currentPage+1);              
        }
    }

    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
});
```

Comment: can you post some code to explicitly show how you did it?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it happens because ImageView intercept touchEvent using onClickListener.
You can use GestureOverlayView with your ImageView - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html

It could handle touch events without intercepting them.

Comment: Thanks, but can I ask how to do it?